# Not Able to Login to Ebay using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, javascript, xpath

I am trying to Login to Ebay site using Selenium. I have successfully identified the user name and password Text boxes using Xpath (and validated the xpaths using the Firefox Eval tool in Firebug).

```
public class LoginTestCase{     
    @Test
    public void LoginEbay() throws InterruptedException 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\selenium_library\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //navigate to Ebay
        driver.get("https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&ru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2F");

        Thread.sleep(20000);
        // Enter user name , password and click on Signin button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Email or username' AND @type='text']")).sendKeys("####@###");            
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password' AND @class='fld']']")).sendKeys("####");
        driver.findElement(By.id("sgnBt")).click();
    }
}
```

I am getting the below warning after which the script Fails.

```
1499976357508   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:41809
1499976358783   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1499976367184   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 62686
Jul 13, 2017 4:06:20 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript warning: https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&ru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2F, line 170: unreachable code after return statement
```

Answer (score 3):

The warnings you see on the console are there because of the `DEBUG` logging turned on by default, they have nothing to do with the real problem as it turns out.

*Your XPath expression is not valid*, `AND` should be lower-cased:

```
//input[@placeholder='Email or username' and @type='text']
                                         ^^^HERE
```

---

As a side note:

- you should not be using hardcoded time delays to tackle timing issues - use `WebDriverWait` and specify what are you waiting for explicitly
- you can use better locators

Improved ebay logging in code snippet:

```
//navigate to Ebay
driver.get("https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&ru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2F");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

// Enter user name , password and click on Signin button
WebElement form = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#mainCnt #SignInForm")));

form.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=text][placeholder='Email or username']")).sendKeys("####@###");
form.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")).sendKeys("test");

form.findElement(By.id("sgnBt")).click();
```